# How can I use regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = r"(Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri)day, (February|March) [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}\s*Day [0-9]{1}"

line = """
Wednesday, February 28, 2018 
Day 4 3:00 Dismissal 
All Day 

Thursday, March 01, 2018 
Day 5 1:30PM Dismissal 
All Day 

Friday, March 02, 2018 
Day 6 3:00 Dismissal 
All Day 

Monday, March 05, 2018 
Day 1 1:30 Dismissal 
All Day 

Tuesday, March 06, 2018 
Day 2 3:00 Dismissal 
All Day 
Tuesday, March 06, 2018"""

result = re.findall(pattern, line)
print(result)
```

Won't work.

Comment: You need to edit your post. Indent code snippets with four spaces so they are formatted as code snippets. Also include a question. "won't work" is not a question. Provide an example of expected output and explain how it differs from actual output.

Comment: Make the groups non-capturing: `r"(?:Mon|Tues|...)day, (?:February|March)..."`.

Comment: When you say print(result), what do you get (e.g. what prints)? And what do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch keys only, group it right:

```
pattern = r"((?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri)day), (February|March) ([0-9]{2}), ([0-9]{4})\s*Day ([0-9]{1})"
```

Will get:

```
[('Wednesday', 'February', '28', '2018', '4'), ('Thursday', 'March', '01', '2018', '5'), ('Friday', 'March', '02', '2018', '6'), ('Monday', 'March', '05', '2018', '1'), ('Tuesday', 'March', '06', '2018', '2')]
```

If you want to catch whole match string, don't group it, (like @ekhumoro said use `?:` before a group):

```
pattern = r"(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri)day, (?:February|March) [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}\s*Day [0-9]{1}"
```

Will get a list of `str`:

```
['Wednesday, February 28, 2018 \nDay 4', 'Thursday, March 01, 2018 \nDay 5', 'Friday, March 02, 2018 \nDay 6', 'Monday, March 05, 2018 \nDay 1', 'Tuesday, March 06, 2018 \nDay 2']
```